# How to create skins(fxml) for buttons and other elements in JavaFX 2.0?

Tags: javafx-2, skinning, fxml, skins

I am wondering if anyone has or knows a link from where I can learn or see how to create skins for buttons, radio buttons, scrollbars etc. using fxml files in JavaFX 2.0.

I have this homework for school and I want it built very well, so I try to do everything like a corporative application, with skins for buttons and other elements.

I would really appreciate any help.

[EDIT] Hi everyone, it has been a while, and i know more now about JavaFX and now when i look back, i see how stupid it sounds, please just forgive me for disrespect and for poor detailed question. Anyway stackoverflow made sure i will never ask any question again.

Comment: what do you call skins? CSS styling? Or real FX skins to totally change control node structure.

Comment: buttonSkin.fxml! FX Skins to totally change control node structure! For example in a button skin i have 4 states: normal, hover, pressed and disabled! You understand what i mean? And how can i call them? from another fxml files(main Pane) or from css with SkinClass(if exists)?

Comment: If the aim of your homework is to customize the states of controls then styling in CSS is sufficient. CSS Styling covers most of use-cases about control's UI design except actions.

Comment: Now is for the homework, but in the next two months i will start working on my bachelor degree and i want to do this as a plus! Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should to prefer search the net first before asking. Here are some results of mine which took a little effort to find out:

- Firstly, intro to [Skinning Architecture in JavaFX](http://fxexperience.com/2009/06/skinning-architecture-in-javafx/) to understand what is going on.
- Another intro about [JavaFX 2.0 Layout: A Class Tour](http://amyfowlersblog.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/javafx2-0-layout-a-class-tour/), to understand distinctions between Group, Region and Control. Since Control implements Skinnable, you may want to add this intro to your bachelor work.
- And here first try of [JavaFX 2.0 Custom Control](http://www.drdobbs.com/blogs/jvm/229400781).
- Finally, dig the code of open source project [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/). You will find there a bunch of custom controls as reference.

Comment: Only the JFXtras may help a little. I am looking for something that extends SkinBase and use the imports: import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase;     Anyway, thanks for the links!